# How to enable button if data grid view has one or more rows in C#

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

I have billing form in which items with their details inserted as rows in data grid view , the form also contains a **save button** which must be enabled if there is one or more rows in data grid view I tried to write this code in **Validating event** of data grid view but it does not give any sense and button is disabled what is the problem?? regards

```
 this.pBillSavebtn.Enabled= pBilldgv.Rows.Count >= 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not give any sense"?

Comment: `this.pBillSavebtn.Enabled= pBilldgv.Rows.Count > 0;` will make it enabled true else false plus there is no need to use an if statement you do not need it in a validation event.. can you show all the relevant code perhaps you could put the code in a different event

Comment: Consider making this check inside the `SelectionChanged Event`

Comment: @MethodMan sir I thought that Count >= 0 will behave like there is an index 0 or more which is referred as first row ,so thanks for your answer I'll keep this in my mind for future .. regards

Comment: @Jim sir your advice meant a lot for me; this is first time I'm using data grid view in my project .. regards

Answer (score 0):

Your program compile with that line?
I'd use:

```
if(pBilldgv.Rows.Count>1) this.pBillSavebtn.Enabled=true;
```

Comment: sir when we talk about indexes we start with 0 not 1 .. regards